# How to traverse a multiple dimensional array in foreach loop to get the table of 4 columns?

Tags: php, foreach

How to traverse a multiple dimensional array in foreach loop to get the table of 4 columns?

I have an array of this format:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1938
                    [prod_id] => 1938
                    [1] => Nokia N96 16GB Sim Free Unlocked Mobile Phone
                    [prod_name] => Nokia N96 16GB Sim Free Unlocked Mobile Phone
                    [2] => 1938_1280387838.jpeg
                    [prod_image] => 1938_1280387838.jpeg
                    [3] => 
                    [prod_model] => 
                    [4] => 0.00
                    [prod_purchase_price] => 0.00
                    [5] => 286.95
                    [prod_retail_price] => 286.95
                    [6] => 295.51
                    [prod_sp_offer_price] => 295.51
                    [7] => 0
                    [prod_stock_qty] => 0
                    [8] => 0
                    [network_id] => 0
                    [9] => 
                    [prod_preorder_text] => 
                    [10] => 2
                    [cat_type_id] => 2
                    [11] => Sim Free Mobiles
                    [cat_type_name] => Sim Free Mobiles
                    [discount] => 0
                )
       }
}
```

Now i need a table which must divide the last child array data in 4 columns of data. using foreach. IN PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Not sure I got this right, you need to display last 4 values of each array element? If so, something like this could be done:</s>

Based on additional information provided, you need to use something like this:

```
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ( $array as $i => $data )
{
    echo '<td>HereBe $data</td>';
    if ( 3 === $i % 4 )
    {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

**Please note**, above code is just an example and is not optimized at all, it is only meant as an idea to help you started. Yes, the result will be correct, but HTML output will not validate in some cases. Can you guess which ones? :)

Comment: I dnt need last 4 values, I want 4 columns in the table to displayed with all data distributed

Comment: Have all 13 values divided into 4 columns?

Comment: I need every array to be displayed in single <td>

Comment: I need 4 <td> each <td> will contain an array and the rows will be divided as per count of data arrays

Comment: So, you need a table with 4 columns and each column contains everything from $arrMainArr[i][j] which basically means you have the same data displayed 4 times?

Comment: Yes, I have other similar arrays I have given an example of one of them. every <TD> will display different array

Comment: Sorry, too confusing. Would it be possible to post entire code and desired output?

Comment: chk this link i need data to be displayed like this: http://www.prepaymania.co.uk/newphones.html

Comment: thnx for support david, but its very much complex

Comment: Do you need any additional help?

Answer (score 1):

sy for e.g your main array is named as $arrMainArr

```
echo '<table border="1">';
foreach($arrMainArr[2] as $arrMains){

    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($arrMains as $key => $value){
            if(!preg_match("/\d/",$key))
            echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

OR Other way is

```
$arrMains = array_keys($arrMainArr[2][0]);

echo '<table border="1"><tr>';
foreach($arrMains as $key => $value){

    if(!preg_match("/\d/",$key))
        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

your array seems to be the result of a database query. if you have control of that query, it will be easier to get the data you want if you modify / amend that query, instead of doing what is essentially a sql query in php. please post the query, and i might help more detailled.

Comment: I have that query in my class file i have to use this array in my template file to display 4 column table structure

Comment: can you change the class file with the query? is it used somewhere else? changing the query will make things easier. please post the query part of the class file and how it is used in the template.

Comment: can you still show us how you get to your array? ie. what is the name of the variable whos contents you posted in your question, and how does it get initialized / call the class with the query?