# While loop problem in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have my markup structure as below:

```
<div>
    <div>value1</div>
    <div>value2</div>
    <div>value3</div>
    <div>value4</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>value5</div>
    <div>value6</div>
    <div>value7</div>
    <div>value8</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I have my data in a PHP result set, let's say I have 9 records so the structure should be as below:

```
<div>
    <div>value1</div>
    <div>value2</div>
    <div>value3</div>
    <div>value4</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>value5</div>
    <div>value6</div>
    <div>value7</div>
    <div>value8</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>value9</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

So, the while loop should run in a way so that it will print the parent div after 4 records printed successfully. But in above I have 9 records so it should close the dive if its the last record.

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't matter, whatever data is there. I just want to run the loop in a way so that it will print the markup in required way.

Comment: Understood, but it's unclear what exactly you are trying to do, at least for me.

Comment: have you been a member for like 10 years?

Comment: Updated question, hope it will help to understand the question, please check!

Comment: I see, the logic you need can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263983/how-to-traverse-a-multiple-dimensional-array-in-foreach-loop-to-get-the-table-of/, just tweak it a bit. Please let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: @ Prashant - can you please tell me that your result set is constant at 9 or it can vary..

Comment: @Sanjay, obviously it can vary. Records are coming from db, so it can be anything 10, 20, 21, 26 etc.

Comment: @David Kuridža, its done. I applied that logic a bit different way and its all working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By getting some idea from logic given **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263983/how-to-traverse-a-multiple-dimensional-array-in-foreach-loop-to-get-the-table-of/4264168#4264168)** I tried following and it works.

```
<div> <!-- started main div -->

<?php 
    $icount = 1;
    $itotal = mysql_num_rows($result_rs);
    while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result_rs)) {
        echo '<div>'.$rs['value'].'</div>'; 

        if ($icount % 4 == 0 && $icount != $itotal){
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
            echo '</div>'; //closed main div

            echo '<div>'; //started new main div
        }

        $icount++;
    }
?>

</div> <!-- closed main div -->
```

That, solved my problem.

Edited: added itotal condition, so when you will have only 4 records per page then also this will work properly.

Answer (score 5):

The preconfig...

```
<?php
    $num_of_results = sizeof($your_array);  
    $loops = ceil($num_of_results/4);
    $k = 0;
?>
```

In your web

```
<?php for($p = 0; $p < $loops; $p++) { ?>
    <div>
        <div>
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < 4 && $k < $num_of_results; $i++) { ?>
            <div><?php echo $your_array[$k]; $k++;?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

That's your problem isnt it?

Comment: Don't want to run 2 loops... :(

Comment: You have a syntax error on your "$k ++;". And why do you use 3 indexes when you can use only two. Just calculate $k as ($p * 4 + $i).

Answer (score 0):

Right, now I know what you're after. I've done this before when showing items in a grid and you need to break each row because of *that* browser.

Anyway, it's ugly but I don't think it gets any easier than this

```
<?php for ($i = 0, $total = count($resultSet); $i < $total; $i += 4) : ?>
<div>
    <?php
    for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) :
    if (!isset($resultSet[$j])) :
    ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php break 2; endif ?>
    <div><?php echo htmlspecialchars($resultSet[$j]) ?></div>
    <?php endfor ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php endfor ?>
```

Comment: @Prashant Updated my answer, should work for you as I've had to do the same before

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++): ?>
    <?php if ($i%4 == 1 && $i != 1): ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <?php endif; //$i%4 == 1 && $i != 1 ?>
    <div>Value <?php echo $i ?></div>
    <?php endfor; //$i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++ ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

or with an array:

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($arr as $k=>$v): ?>
    <?php if (($k+1)%4 == 1 && $k != 0): ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <?php endif; //($k+1)%4 == 1 && $k != 0 ?>
    <div><?php echo $v ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; //$arr as $k=>$v ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

or with a mysqli resultset:

```
<div>
    <?php $count = 1 ?>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <?php if ($count%4 == 1 && $count != 1): ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <?php endif; //$count%4 == 1 && $count != 1 ?>
    <div><?php echo $row['value'] ?></div>
    <?php $count++ ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use modulo to "close" a div?

```
<div>
<?php foreach($data as $key => $value) : ?>
    <div><?php echo $value ?></div>
<?php if($key % 4 == 0 && $key != 0) : // add a clearing div, close the first group and open another one ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>
<? endforeach ?>
<?php if($key % 4 != 0) : // div has not been closed as the number of records % 4 was not equal 0 ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
<? endif ?>
```