# Constructing HTML to output a set of numbers 5 per line

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am realy stuck with part of my php code! I have a range of numbers from 1 to 40 say that I pull from a table in my database and out put onto the screen using a while loop! with these numbers I am using a submit button which i will replace with a image button later on! Just now i can only get them in one line using a table but I want to get them into groups of say 5 or so colums and then go to next line print the next 5 or so colums! I have been trying for loops but they print out 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, etc. in diffrent lines which is not what i want! I want,

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 
etc
```

Please help me i have been baffeld with this for ages this is my code so far!

```
<?     
  $q3 = "SELECT * FROM tblgame";
  $r3 = mysql_query($q3);
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($r3))
  {
    $game_cost = $row2['game_cost'];      

    echo "<p>Game ID: ".$row2['game_id'];
    echo "<br>Game Day: ".$game_day;
    echo "<br>Next Game Date: ".$row2['game_date_day']."/".$row2['game_date_month']."/".$row2['game_date_year'];

    $fyear = $row2['game_date_year'];
    $fmonth = $row2['game_date_month'];
    $fday = $row2['game_date_day'];
    $tmonth = $date_month;
    $tyear = $date_year;
    $tday = $date_day;
    $days_between = abs((mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $fmonth, $fday, $fyear) - mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $tmonth, $tday, $tyear))/(60*60*24)); 

    echo "<br>Days till next draw: ". $days_between;
    echo "<br />Game Cost: £".$row2['game_cost']."</p>";
 ?>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <?   
    $q4 = "SELECT * FROM tblnewgameitem WHERE game_id = $row2[game_id] ORDER BY 'game_number' ";
    $r4 = mysql_query($q4);
    $n1 = mysql_num_rows($r4);
    $i=0;
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($r4))
    {
    ?>
     <td>
     <?
       if($row3['user_email'] == "")
       { 
       ?>
           <form action="buyanumber.php" method="POST">
             <input type="hidden" name="game_id" value="<?echo $row2['game_id'];?>">
             <input type="hidden" name="num" value="<? echo $row3['game_number']; ?>">
             <input type="submit" value="<?echo $row3['game_number'];?>" name="submit">
           </form>                                
       <?
       }
       else
       {
         $n = $n + 1;
         echo " ".$row3['game_number']." ";       
       }
       ?>
     </td>
     <?
   }
   ?>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Please help me i have been stuck on this problem for a good number of days and its driving me loopy lol!

Thank you
Stephen

Comment: Consider using a question title that actually helps focus on the code in question, you're far more likely to attract the attention of people who know something about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4397762/283366

Comment: Fixed the title. Also, please note the location of the period, or "full stop" key on your keyboard - between `,` and `/` on a standard US QWERTY layout - and consider it as an altervative to `SHIFT + 1`. ;)

Comment: Doesnt stackoverflow force a little 'how to ask a good question' message on you when you write your first question? Or was the author trying to see how many of the rules he could break in a single question?

Answer (score 0):

nested for-loops is the key:

```
$list=array();
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($r3)) $list[] = $row2;

$countList = count($list);
$cols = 5;
$rows = ceil($countList / $maxPerRow);

for ($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++) {
    echo 'opening stuff per row... <tr> or something';
    for ($j=0; $j<$rows; $j++) {
        echo 'your stuff per item... might be somthing like <td>s';
    }

    echo 'closing stuff per row... </tr> or something';
}
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the 'real' problem lays somewhere between `<table>` and `</table>` and that you want to put the values returned by the fourth query (for some reason mapped to `$row3`) in a table with 5 columns.

Using the PHP modulo operator ('%'), you could do something like this:

```
<?php
    $r4 = <your mysql_query>
    $i = 0;
    while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($r4)) {
        if ($i % 5 == 0) { // true for 0, 5, 10, ...
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo "<td>";
        // what you want to put between your <td> tags comes here
        echo "</td>";
        if (($i+1) % 5 == 0) { // true for 4, 9, 14, ...
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    // if the number of rows is not a multiple of 5, we must clean up after ourselves:
    if ($i % 5 != 0) {
        echo "<td colspan=\"" + (5-($i % 5)) + "\">&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

I haven't tested the code myself.

For the sake of clearity, please consider using proper indentation and consistent variable naming in your code. Also note that using a proper title and less exclamation marks in your question would improve the clearity of it.