# for each loop increment more than one in php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i have one class in php returning number of records.
i use table to display name like that

```
foreach($getArtist as $getArtist)
{
echo "<tr><td>".$getArtist['name']."</td></tr>";
}
```

this works fine and display each name in one row

now i want to display 3 names in one row

```
foreach($getArtist as $getArtist)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$getArtist['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$getArtist['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$getArtist['name']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

but this is displaying each name 3 times, but i need to display 3 names in one row then other 3 names in other row and when record finish loop finish

Comment: This is one of the most common "problems" for novice developers and it might be difficult to tackle. So far, what have you tried? Solving this problem is much more rewarding if you do it yourself instead of someone giving you the code (plus you probably won't understand the solution to the problem that way).

Comment: possible duplicate of [While loop problem in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397762/while-loop-problem-in-php)

Comment: Please don't name your "each" variable the same as the array. This is just asking for trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach (array_chunk($getArtist, 3) as $artists) {
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach (array_pad($artists, 3, array('name' => '&nbsp;')) as $artist) {
    echo '<td>' . $artist['name'] . '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

**Edit**: *quickly inserting DaveRandoms fix to Phils comment* ;)

Answer (score 3):

Several ways to tackle this one.  One of the ways is to split up / chunk the rows of data.

```
$rowSize = 3;
$rowsOfArtists = array_chunk($getArtists, $rowSize);

if ($youNeedYourTableBalanced) {
   $rows = intval(ceil(count($getArtists) / $rowSize));
   $paddedLength = $rows * $rowSize;
   $paddedArtists = array_pad($getArtists, $paddedLength, '&nbsp;');
   $rowsOfArtists = array_chunk($paddedArtists, $rowSize);
}

foreach ($rowsOfArtists as $artists)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($artists as $getArtists)
    {
        echo "<td>" . $getArtist['name'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: You could end up with an unbalanced table row if the last chunk contains less than three elements

Comment: @Phil good catch, but easily overcome with [array_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php)...

Comment: True,  depending on the css, padding the last chunk with artist names '&nbsp;' may be needed.

Comment: @rrehbein you can just make you first line `$rowsOfArtists = array_chunk(array_pad($getArtists, (($pad = count($getArtists) + (3 - (count($getArtists) % 3))) < 3) ? $pad : count($getArtists), '&nbsp;'), 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.   Try to review each approach outlined because this is a common programming task, so make sure you understand how to solve it...

```
VAR $ctr = 0;
VAR $outLine = "";


    foreach($getArtist as $getArtist)
    {
    $ctr = $ctr +1;
    if ($ctr = 3)
       {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo $outline;
            echo "<td>".$getArtist['name']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $outline = "";
       }
    else
       { 
          $outline = $outline . "<td>".$getArtist['name']."</td>";
       }

    }

    if ($outline > "")
     {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo $outline;
            for ($i = $ctr; $i <= 3; $i++) {
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
             }
            echo "</td>";

     }
```

Comment: Why the `VAR` declarations? And what happened to all those `;`s?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the semi-colons (happens when I switch languages).  I add them back...  VAR is a habit of mine, probably carry over from 30 years ago when I was writing DIM in my BASICA programs...